# How to add items to class property array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, properties, array-merge

I have a class property which is an array. I have some $data array which I would like to add to that array without using a foreach loop.

Check out this sample code:

```
<?php
    class A {
    public $y = array();
    public function foo() {
        $data = array('apples', 'pears', 'oranges');
        array_merge($this->y, $data);
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->foo();
print_r($a->y);
assert(sizeof($a->y)==3);
```

Expected result:

```
Array (
    [0] => apples
    [1] => pears
    [2] => oranges
)
```

Actual result:

```
Array ( )
PHP Warning:  assert(): Assertion failed on line 16
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/array_merge - it RETURNS the new merged array. you don't capture that returned array, so the merge is destroyed and essentially pointless.

Comment: array_merge returns an array. try `$this->y = array_merge($this->y, $data);`

Comment: Definitely an RTFM moment for me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function definition as follows:

```
public function foo() {
        $data = array('apples', 'pears', 'oranges');
        $this->y = array_merge($this->y, $data);
}
```

The [documentation](http://php.net/array_merge) clearly states that the merged array is returned back. So, the original array passed in the parameter remains untouched.

Comment: *Hits own head* Given that I have used array_merge dozens of times before, this is definitely an example of a time when the problem is between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: @DanielJames no problem, just mark as an answer and upvote so that this is closed...

Comment: StackOverflow does not let the author mark an answer as Accepted until 5 minutes have passed. You will get the accepted answer, DW :-)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the 4 min rule.. Looks like I have to ask some question to know certain things.. Happy learning :)